# Rendering MathML expressions inside ReactJS component

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, mathjax, mathml

I am looking to render MathML expressions in my Ionic app where we use ReactJS. We are using Mathjax library which renders LaTex expressions properly but throws error for MathML.

I get the below error.

---

Error: Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(..., .e.2.$A,< math xmlns=0"http=2//www=1w3=1org/1998/Math/MathML" display=0"block" >

....

,false.0.0): Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a  when using tables, nesting tags like ,

, or , or using non-SVG elements in an  parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID ``.

---

I am not able to see any solutions to this. When I used it directly in AngularJS using $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code), it works perfectly. Appreciate inputs. Thanks.

```
var MathMLReact = React.createClass({displayName: 'MathMLReact',
render: function(){
    return (React.createElement("div",null, "Hello. ",this.props.reactStuff));
}
});
```

Adding JSFiddle link [myJSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amrudesh/3vbbpg4u/22/).

Comment: Does it work with very simple expressions, say a single variable?

Comment: Please include a minimal test case.  You may just need to step one further level outside react, and do your mathml stuff in componentDidMount/componentDidUpdate.

Comment: Not even on a simple expression. Added JSFiddle link.

Comment: Works after using dangerouslySetInnerHTML. See JSFiddle link [fixedExample](http://jsfiddle.net/amrudesh/3vbbpg4u/23/).

Comment: There's really no other way -- your original sample inserted the MathML as a text-string. But it needs to be a regular DOM node. You can try to create a MathJax-custom script tag -- see http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/model.html#how-mathematics-is-stored-in-the-page

Comment: Thanks @PeterKrautzberger . Will explore the mathjax custom script method too. The insertion as string works since its a part of virtual DOM. Regular DOM node will be created by React Later.

Comment: I see. Then that was not working -- the original fiddle had the MathML as text content not DOM nodes.

Comment: Feel free to try out [better-react-mathjax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-react-mathjax). The docs contain examples and sandboxes with MathML. I wrote it because I think that most MathJax libraries for React are old and poorly maintained. Let me know what you think!